# Which standard exception throw if there is error in a middle of operation?

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception, c++-cli, standards

According to [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229007.aspx) I shouldn't use `Exception` directly to throw. When re-factoring code I changed most of them to

- `InvalidOperationException` if method call is inadequate (wrong pre-requisites, time, state, etc);
- `TimeoutExeption` whenever there is a timeout;
- `ArgumentException` (and related - `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`) when method is called with wrong parameters;

However, I stuck to figure out what exception is *most suitable* when method did half of operation (so parameters and state was ok), but then a problem occurs (in my case it's communication with external device, when it suddenly reports "omg error").

**What standard exception** should I use (I don't want to derive my own) in case of *middle-progress* or *finalizing* exception? Shouldn't be  a hard question, but ...

Comment: Not every case is covered by an existing exception in the .NET Framework. Middle-progress doesn't really seems like a good exception to create but given your description of the problem, why wouldn't you create a DeviceCommunicationException derived from System.Exception? That seems like it would be completely appropriate and descriptive of the actual problem that you experience.

Comment: @JamieSee, if I do it once, then I couldn't stop doing it everywhere (more of `DeviceCommunication..` exceptions will appears) ;) So there is nothing more-less *default*? `InvalidOperationException` actually fits (for user of method the reason is a *bad* call while device was not *100% operational*, his problems aye). :)

Comment: It's always a bit of a judgment call with that kind of thing. Microsoft does provide a little guidance on Exception design at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014.aspx that's worth a look. My own opinion is that exceptions should be descriptive of the actual problem encountered rather than the phase of a particular process. I also try to look at whether or not I can reduce the problems that would cause me to throw an exception. Is it appropriate to poll the device for a little while to see if it reaches an operational state and then throw a TimeoutException if it does not?

Comment: Without a more specific question, no good answer can be offered. But in terms of dealing with a communications failure, if you don't want to define a custom exception, I would say that IOException is a good choice. Even a custom exception should probably inherit IOException. Alternatively, depending on the exact nature of the error, possible InvalidDataException would be appropriate (i.e. communication is working, but there's something wrong with the data itself...wrong format, corrupted bytes, etc.)

Comment: Declare your own OmgException type.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the situation. If it is a web service (or possibly a website) you could throw a 500 Internal Server Error.

In my c# wcf service in some circumstances I do the following:

```
 throw new System.ServiceModel.Web.WebFaultException<string>(
                "Descriptive error message",
                System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```